# zsh: use completions for command X when I type command Y

Tags: zsh, tab-completion, programmable-completion

In zsh, I have a function called `g` which acts like this:

- with no arguments, call `git status`
- with one or more arguments, delegate to git with all given arguments - i.e. call `git $@`

I would like the tab completions for `g` to be exactly the same as for `git`. I can achieve this with `alias g=git`, but that doesn't allow me to call `status` by default (the first point above).

How can I delegate to the completion for `git`?

In bash, I simply did `complete -F _git g` which re-uses git's completion function. With zsh, git's completion looks much more complex, and I wan't able to find a similar solution.

I'd guess there's some function in zsh to say "pretend I typed command [x], what would you complete it to?". If I knew what that was, it should be simple enough to use a function to delegate to it. But I've found no such function in the manuals.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on how to make it work in bash!

Comment: If you can change your function to conditionally print the commands it would execute instead of actually executing them, see this answer by yut23: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72905491/21501

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation for [`compdef`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#IDX1603) says this:

> The function `compdef` can be used to associate existing completion functions with new commands. For example,
>
> ```
> compdef _pids foo
> ```

But adapting it (`_git` is the usual completion function for *git*) did not produce a working result for me (even after `_git` had been autoloaded):

```
compdef _git g
```

I was able to get it to work via `_dispatch` though:

```
compdef '_dispatch git git' g
```

Comment: That's weird. I have the same thing happening, but other completion functions work just fine with the first command.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much! As for why the first doesn't work, Perhaps the completion for _git is sufficiently custom that just redirecting it isn't enough to get it to respond with anything useful? (i.e maybe it checks that the command starts with "git")

Comment: Any idea how `compdef '_dispatch git git' g` can be adjusted to make g auto-complete like git-status, rather than just git?

Comment: This works for me when I run it directly in a zsh shell, but for some reason it doesn't work when I put it my `.zshrc`.

Comment: If you want to have a subcommand like `git status`, then apparently (by trial and error) I came up with `compdef '_dispatch _git-status git' gst`

Comment: @DarioSeidl If you put it into your .zshrc, make sure that it is after your call `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`

Answer (score 0):

This same function had stopped working for me after a change-around of configs.

```sh
# in ~/.zsh/functions/g.zsh

# # No arguments: `git status`
# # With arguments: acts like `git`
g() {
  if [[ $# > 0 ]]; then
    git "$@"
  else
    git status
  fi
}
```

It's actually important to place just the function in `~/.zsh/functions/g.zsh` and create a compdef in `~/.zsh/completions/_g`:

```sh
#compdef g
compdef g=git
```

Then, in `.zshrc`:

```sh
fpath=($HOME/.zsh/completions $fpath)

# load custom executable functions
for function in ~/.zsh/functions/*.zsh; do
  source $function
done

# completion
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

Not sure if the order is important. I think when the compdef is in a separate folder, it works with any order.

Got the `g` function from here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/functions/g

https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/completion/_g

Thanks Thoughtbot!