# how to "copy" existing completions to other commands in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a custom script that takes hostnames as parameters. I know that I can easily copy the existing completion of ssh like this:

```
compdef myscript=ssh
```

But that only enables completion of the 1st parameter. Is there an easy way to enable the same completion for *all* parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an *easy* method to enable completion for a custom command. Assuming you've got a command `foo` with a bunch of allowable arguments `bar`, `bas` **or** `baz`, then the completion is easy: you can either have `foo bar`, `foo bas`, or `foo baz`. If they're not `or`'d, though, you could have any combination of the three.

It gets somewhat worse when you've got a 'depth' of more than 1 (`bar` can take arguments `car`, `cas` and `caz`, for example).

In `zsh`, my general understanding is that completion for commands is detailed in `completion functions`. These functions are *application specific*, because the arguments for each application are specific to those applications. As an example, the `tmux` (a terminal multiplexer, similar to `screen`, in case you're not familiar) has a completion function that's fairly complex: [here's a link](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob;f=Completion/Unix/Command/_tmux;hb=HEAD).

If you want to write your own completion functions, the documentation is available and accessible. Here are a bunch of links that I'm (slowly) working my way through - they'll definitely tell you how to get completion working, but there's a lot of reading. The Z-Shell is a complex beast.

- [Z-Shell completion introduction](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/)
- [Z-Shell functions: Writing and loading your own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33898/18678)
- [ZSH Users Guide, Ch. 6: "Completion, old and new"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html)

You're specifically interested in enabling completion for hostname-like arguments, and you've singled out `ssh` as the idea. The `zsh` completion function for `ssh` is defined in `Completion/Unix/Command/_ssh`, if you've got the ZSH source. If not, here's a [link](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob_plain;f=Completion/Unix/Command/_ssh;hb=95f02efe7e2aeae654b05acb0f36185f7e14957d).

---

Of course, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221239/zsh-use-completions-for-command-x-when-i-type-command-y) is rather similar. `compdef` alone may do what you want, if `myscript` and `ssh` parameters are identical enough.