# Complete a command (with arguments) like another command (with other arguments)

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

`compdef cmd1=service` can be used to define a completion alias, however, that works only when the arguments are going to be the same.

For example, consider a helper script which rewrites some arguments before executing another command:

```
| What is typed | What is executed           |
|---------------+----------------------------|
| s             | systemctl                  |
| s q           | systemctl status           |
| s q foo       | systemctl status foo       |
| s j foo       | journalctl --unit foo      |
| s r foo       | sudo systemctl restart foo |
```

We can ask the script to print the arguments it would execute, so e.g. `PRINT_ONLY=1 s` would print just `systemctl`.

Assuming completion is already set up for `systemctl` / `journalctl` / `sudo`, how would one define a zsh completion for such a script? Rather than redundantly reimplementing completion for those commands, how to implement completion for `s` such that the completion system is invoked with a transformed command -- i.e. something like `function _s() { get_completions $(PRINT_ONLY=1 s "$@") ; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should go in a file named `_s` somewhere on your `$fpath`:

```sh
#compdef s

local -a orig_command new_words
orig_command=("${words[@]}")
if [[ $words[-1] == '' ]]; then
  # remove an empty word at the end, which the completion system cares about
  orig_command[-1]=()
fi
# split the rewritten command into words using the shell parser
new_words=("${(z)$(PRINT_ONLY=1 "${orig_command[@]}")}")
if [[ $words[-1] == '' ]]; then
  # restore the empty word if we removed it
  new_words+=('')
fi
# update the cursor position
CURRENT=$(( CURRENT - $#words + $#new_words ))
words=("${new_words[@]}")
# restart completion with the rewritten command
_normal
```

Note: this doesn't do any error handling and just assumes that any unknown arguments will be passed to the default command (e.g. `s start foo` -> `systemctl start foo`). If that's not the case, let me know how `s` behaves in those cases and I can update the completion script.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Since I could edit the helper script, I modified it to output transformed parameters as NUL-terminated, which allowed simplifying the completion further: https://gist.github.com/CyberShadow/d453fd5ab13d859207b7c03f768b4b94